# How can I make black color to transparent color?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have image:

```
Image<Bgr,Byte> someImage = new Image<Bgr,Byte>(someImage.jpg);
```

[image]

How can I make all black pixels(black color) transparent?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far and where do you get stuck?

Comment: I'm newer in image processing so I will be thenkfull if you advice me how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example about  how to use alpha to make background transparent on this [thread](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24463/how-to-remove-black-background-from-grabcut-output/?comment=24786#comment-24786).

Comment: Haris what is the meaning of this row :
Mat dst;//(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC4);

Comment: Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC4); mean initialize Mat of respecified size and channel of uchar type.   In Opencv C++ standard no need to initialize destination image in merge() operation, that's why I commented that line. In Java you may need to create destination Mat as source.

Comment: I guess in C# I nees to create destination Mat as source alsow?

Comment: Hey Haris, how would Mat rgb[3]; split(src,rgb); Mat rgba[4]=rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2],alpha}; merge(rgba,4,dst); look like in c#?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find a way to define your image in such a way that it uses the **alpha channel**. If you want details, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) is the link for **RGBA** color space.

Basically, you need to initialize a `CV_8UC4` image. Keep in mind to initialize all pixels to zero before you start (basically, the entire matrix will be black before you start putting values in)..